# One particular dataset is benchmark for image classification in the computer vision and machine learning literature

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, deep-learning

Whenever I read articles about dataset (like MNIST and CIFAR 10), mostly I find statement like,

**CIFAR-10 is standard benchmark dataset for image classification in the computer vision and machine learning literature.**

If especially, I'll talk about the convolution neural network (deep learning) then, as per knowledge, the accuracy of the network architecture depends on dataset used.

I am really confused with the statement I did bold above.

What does exactly that statement mean?

Thanks in advance if someone can help me by giving real life example.

Comment: If you find it a silly question, then answer it. Don't down vote it.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not how it works. Users are free to anonymously downvote a question if they find it not useful or lacking research effort. Consider taking them as a hint to improve the question. In particular, your question is focused on machine learning, and is not directly related to programming, making it off-topic here. You may find that [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) or [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com) are a better fit for these questions.

Comment: @E_net4... Actually I am also involved in deep learning and for doing any research you should have the clear knowledge of very fundamental thing like what I asked. If someone don't know the why we need the dataset as benchmark, how we can interpret it with our neural network, whether the network is dataset specific, can we use the network giving good accuracy  on the benchmark dataset to train the other dataset...

Comment: I am not contesting whether data scientists into deep learning should know that. I'm just saying that your question is not appropriate here. Answering off-topic questions is a no no.

Comment: I know @MitchWheat, benchmark refers to the point of reference. So, I can say the benchmark is used to compare two network architecture trained of the "benchmark dataset". But in real life, everyone is not going to train cifar10 dataset. Everyone is having their own dataset to train to their project or development. If I have two CNN model, suppose m1 and m2. For CIFAR10 dataset, m1 gives better accuracy than m2. It doesn't mean that for my dataset also m1 would give good accuracy. So, I was bit confuse with this.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "benchmarking" has been defined [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmark_(computing)) as:

> In computing, a benchmark is the act of running a computer program, a set of programs, or other operations, in order to assess the relative performance of an object, normally by running a number of standard tests and trials against it.

In the computer vision community, some researchers focus their efforts on improving image classification performance on benchmark datasets. There are many benchmark datasets, e.g. MNIST, CIFAR-10, ImageNet. The existence of benchmark datasets means researchers can more easily compare the performance of their proposed method against existing methods. The researchers know that (generally speaking) everyone who benchmarks their method on this dataset has access to the same input data.

In some cases, a dataset provider keeps a leaderboard of the best-performing results on their benchmark dataset. For example, ImageNet keeps a record of the performance of the methods submitted to the benchmark contest each year. Here is an example of [the best-performing methods for the 2017 ImageNet object classification task](http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2017/results#loc).

[image: ImageNet 2018 Classification best results]